# Trying to connect my node.js to Heroku PostgreSQL database. Following Heroku Postgres tutorial

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm following these two Heroku tutorials:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs

and

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

I have the 'hello world' app working. But I am getting an error when I add the node.js code to connect to postgreSQL.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "node-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "pg": "2.x",
    "express": "3.1.x"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.2.x"
  }
}
```

My web.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});

var pg = require('pg');

pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
  client.query('SELECT * FROM your_table', function(err, result) {
    done();
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(result.rows);
  });
});
```

My Heroku postgres database is working well and I can connect to it directly with

```
heroku pg:psql
```

Here are my logs:

```
2013-09-29T13:13:34.777156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-29T13:13:34.784018+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-09-29T13:13:34.787193+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:72
2013-09-29T13:13:34.787469+00:00 app[web.1]:         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2013-09-29T13:13:34.787642+00:00 app[web.1]:               ^
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]: error: relation "junk" does not exist
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.parseE (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:546:11)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.parseMessage (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:375:17)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at null.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:92:20)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790791+00:00 app[web.1]:     at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
2013-09-29T13:13:34.790968+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
2013-09-29T13:13:36.511975+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2013-09-29T13:13:36.527681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2013-09-29T13:21:22+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-29T13:21:38+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-09-29T13:21:39.239935+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-09-29T13:21:40.589773+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node web.js`
2013-09-29T13:21:41.345806+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 20977
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]: { [error: relation "your_table" does not exist]
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   length: 101,
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   detail: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   severity: 'ERROR',
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   hint: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   position: '15',
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: '42P01',
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   name: 'error',
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   internalPosition: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368512+00:00 app[web.1]:   where: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368512+00:00 app[web.1]:   file: 'parse_relation.c',
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368512+00:00 app[web.1]:   line: '864',
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368323+00:00 app[web.1]:   internalQuery: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:21:41.368512+00:00 app[web.1]:   routine: 'parserOpenTable' }
2013-09-29T13:21:41.938926+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-29T13:21:38.600520+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 95a0a35 by *********@gmail.com
2013-09-29T13:21:38.625733+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v17 created by *******@gmail.com
2013-09-29T13:22:08.383050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=pure-lake-7106.herokuapp.com fwd="58.7.243.156" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=12
2013-09-29T13:22:08.383327+00:00 app[web.1]: - - - [Sun, 29 Sep 2013 13:22:08 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/28.0.1500.71 Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
2013-09-29T13:22:10.046808+00:00 app[web.1]: - - - [Sun, 29 Sep 2013 13:22:10 GMT] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/28.0.1500.71 Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
2013-09-29T13:22:10.049179+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=pure-lake-7106.herokuapp.com fwd="58.7.243.156" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=34
2013-09-29T13:29:40+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-29T13:30:07.484077+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy a2cc795 by xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
2013-09-29T13:30:07.515481+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v18 created by xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
2013-09-29T13:30:07+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-09-29T13:30:08.016355+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-09-29T13:30:10.017792+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node web.js`
2013-09-29T13:30:10.099473+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-09-29T13:30:11.008770+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 47344
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   name: 'error',
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   length: 101,
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   severity: 'ERROR',
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: '42P01',
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   detail: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   position: '15',
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]: { [error: relation "your_table" does not exist]
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   internalPosition: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   internalQuery: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065840+00:00 app[web.1]:   where: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065840+00:00 app[web.1]:   file: 'parse_relation.c',
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065840+00:00 app[web.1]:   line: '864',
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065840+00:00 app[web.1]:   routine: 'parserOpenTable' }
2013-09-29T13:30:11.065531+00:00 app[web.1]:   hint: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:30:11.482704+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-29T13:30:11.651117+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-09-29T13:30:17.729604+00:00 app[web.1]: - - - [Sun, 29 Sep 2013 13:30:17 GMT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/28.0.1500.71 Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
2013-09-29T13:30:19.361615+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=pure-lake-7106.herokuapp.com fwd="58.7.243.156" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=34
2013-09-29T13:30:19.364457+00:00 app[web.1]: - - - [Sun, 29 Sep 2013 13:30:19 GMT] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/28.0.1500.71 Chrome/28.0.1500.71 Safari/537.36"
2013-09-29T13:30:17.728815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=pure-lake-7106.herokuapp.com fwd="58.7.243.156" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=12
2013-09-29T13:32:28+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-09-29T13:32:43.338858+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d4cf2ba by xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
2013-09-29T13:32:43.359317+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v19 created by xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
2013-09-29T13:32:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-09-29T13:32:43.746015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2013-09-29T13:32:45.354842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node web.js`
2013-09-29T13:32:46.098651+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on 37156
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]: { [error: relation "your_table" does not exist]
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: '42P01',
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   name: 'error',
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   length: 101,
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   hint: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   position: '15',
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   severity: 'ERROR',
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   detail: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127561+00:00 app[web.1]:   where: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127561+00:00 app[web.1]:   routine: 'parserOpenTable' }
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   internalPosition: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127328+00:00 app[web.1]:   internalQuery: undefined,
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127561+00:00 app[web.1]:   file: 'parse_relation.c',
2013-09-29T13:32:47.127561+00:00 app[web.1]:   line: '864',
2013-09-29T13:32:47.197293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-09-29T13:32:50.505267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-09-29T13:32:53.246120+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-09-29T14:39:50.833246+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2013-09-29T14:39:52.828292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2013-09-29T14:39:54.545662+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2013-09-29T14:39:54.559151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
```

I get this erroe when I do a foreman start

```
p$ foreman start
12:39:41 web.1  | started with pid 13983
12:39:41 web.1  | Listening on 5000
12:39:41 web.1  | /home/roland/github/heroku_app/web.js:18
12:39:41 web.1  |   client.query('SELECT * FROM your_table', function(err, result) {
12:39:41 web.1  |          ^
12:39:41 web.1  | TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of null
12:39:41 web.1  |     at /home/roland/github/heroku_app/web.js:18:10
12:39:41 web.1  |     at /home/roland/github/heroku_app/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:54:25
12:39:41 web.1  |     at /home/roland/github/heroku_app/node_modules/pg/node_modules/generic-pool/lib/generic-pool.js:271:11
12:39:41 web.1  |     at /home/roland/github/heroku_app/node_modules/pg/lib/pool.js:27:26
12:39:41 web.1  |     at null.<anonymous> (/home/roland/github/heroku_app/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:169:9)
12:39:41 web.1  |     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
12:39:41 web.1  |     at null.<anonymous> (/home/roland/github/heroku_app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:97:12)
12:39:41 web.1  |     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
12:39:41 web.1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
12:39:41 web.1  |     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
12:39:41 web.1  | exited with code 8
12:39:41 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
SIGTERM received
```

EDIT my console.logs;

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.logger());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  response.send('Hello World!');
  console.log("hello roland");
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on " + port);
});

var pg = require('pg');


pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
   console.log(err+"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  client.query('SELECT * FROM your_table', function(err, result) {
    done();
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    console.log(result.rows);
  });
});
```

Comment: In your `client.connect()` callback, what is the value of `err`? It seems like it works at least part of the time, since `your_table` is being queried (as is evident from the pg logs). It doesn't exist, btw.

Comment: @NitzanShaked, I don't know, I didn't write this code but pasted it directly form the tutorial. Should I do a console.log(err): ? and see.

Comment: @NitzanShaked I get: console.log(err+"!!!!!!");
            ^
ReferenceError: err is not defined

Comment: post your code. It should be. Probably put the console log in a wrong place.

Comment: @NitzanShaked I posted the code in an edit. I specifically used two console.logs so as not to miss it.

Comment: The `console.log()` should be *inside* the `pg.connect()` callback. Immediately above the `client.query()` line and immediately below `pg.connect()` line.

Comment: @NitzanShaked er = null

Comment: @NitzanShaked Don't leave me hanging lol. That is null even in the new position you describe.

Comment: @rolandsharp: it seems like this is going to be a long discussion in comments here, and this is frowned upon in SO. I would try to help out a bit if you could chat, but your SO reputation prohibits that as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's Heroku's problem. The "process.env.DATABASE_URL" variable they tell you to use in pg.connect is not functioning.

A simple

```
console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
```

Will show that this variable is undefined.

Until Heroku offers a fix, you can hard-code the connection URL as the first argument to pg.connect().

To find your credentials, you can go to your app's PostgreSQL add-on connection settings through http://heroku.com.

The new pg.connect method will look like

```
var connectionString = "postgres://*USERNAME*:*PASSWORD*@*HOST*:*PORT*/*DATABASE*"

pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
   client.query('SELECT * FROM your_table', function(err, result) {
      done();
      if(err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(result.rows);
   });
});
```

Comment: why not use the heroku toolbelts command 'heroku config:set VAR=value' that way it isn't in your repo?

Comment: `config:set` sets the variable for the dyno. For local variables the `.env` file can be used: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local#copy-heroku-config-vars-to-your-local-env-file

Comment: I upvoted this because it seemed true in my experience, but I later was able to get it working. For me, the problem was (somehow) that the wrong version of postgres was being used. That doesn't seem to make sense to me either, but I documented my experience here: https://github.com/Requarks/wiki/issues/2949

Comment: Heroku will provide the URL in their environment variables. If you don't use it, when Heroku randomly rotates the credentials, your app will break. Basically, never hardcode the connection string.

Answer (score 14):

If the above answers fall a little short for anyone (they did for me) - try appending `?ssl=true` to the end of your DATABASE_URL environment variable. Credit to the author of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25807651/2329708). Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `heroku pg:info` command to list all your databases. There you will find the exact databse url that you can use in your app - it should be something like that: `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_DBNAME_URL`. This url can be used in node.js application:

```
pg.connect(process.env.HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_DBNAME_URL, function(err, client, done) {
   client.query('SELECT * FROM your_table', function(err, result) {
      done();
      if(err) return console.error(err);
      console.log(result.rows);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `heroku pg:promote` like so:

`heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHATEVER_URL`

This should set the DATABASE_URL variable on Heroku's side.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend hardcoding the URL, because you may be willing to create staging app with the same code.

You may use `nconf` to make sure Heroku's environment variables (stored in a `.env` file, read by `foreman` when launching your app with `Procfile`).

You may create a `config.js` file gathering your variables:

```
const nconf = require('nconf')

module.exports = nconf.argv().env()
```

Then use it to retrieve your variables:

```
import config from './config'

config.get('HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_DBNAME_URL')
```

Note that you could use the exact same setup as Heroku on your local machine. All you need is to create a `Procfile` to describe how to start your server and a `.env` file with you local variables (e.g. your local postgresql database url). Check https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while connecting to my NestJS (NodeJS app) to Heroku PostgreSQL database. I fixed it by adding the SSL: true property in the ormconfig.json file.

Use the following code snippet for a NodeJS app:

```js
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true,
});

client.connect();

client.query('SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;', (err, res) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  for (let row of res.rows) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
  }
  client.end();
});
```

And for a Java app:

```java
@Configuration
public class MainConfig {

@Bean
public BasicDataSource dataSource() throws URISyntaxException {
    URI dbUri = new URI(System.getenv("DATABASE_URL"));

    String username = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[0];
    String password = dbUri.getUserInfo().split(":")[1];
    String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://" + dbUri.getHost() + ':' + dbUri.getPort() + dbUri.getPath() + "?sslmode=require";

    BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    basicDataSource.setUrl(dbUrl);
    basicDataSource.setUsername(username);
    basicDataSource.setPassword(password);

    return basicDataSource;
}}
```

Note: Follow this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-node-js) for other technologies database connection details.