# Cant connect to postgres database?

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, heroku

Ok. I have followed all directions listed at Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database and am trying to complete the last step - getting my page to print the contents of a database I apparently just provisioned with PostGres.

This is what Postgres looks like for me:

[image]

Heroku's sample says to connect to database like this:

```
app.get('/db', function (request, response) {
  pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', function(err, result) {
      done();
      if (err)
       { console.error(err); response.send("Error " + err); }
      else
       { response.render('pages/db', {results: result.rows} ); }
    });
  });
});
```

But when running my page with this I get that the table 'test_table' does not exist.

[image]

Following this and manually putting in URL for the database [Trying to connect my node.js to Heroku PostgreSQL database. Following Heroku Postgres tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085609/trying-to-connect-my-node-js-to-heroku-postgresql-database-following-heroku-pos)
I get this error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I can't for anything get the contents of the db. How do I do this?

POSSIBLE ISSUE: I do not have an .env file and don't know how to configure one. not sure if that is affecting anything

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you'll need to [create a `test_table` table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html). From the [bottom of the page you posted](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#provision-a-database):

> ```
> $ heroku pg:psql
> psql (9.5.2, server 9.6.2)
> SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
> Type "help" for help.
> => create table test_table (id integer, name text);
> CREATE TABLE
> => insert into test_table values (1, 'hello database');
> INSERT 0 1
> => \q
> ```

Comment: I did that and all came back well. Problem is in Postgres it doesn't appear I have a table named "test_table" if Im understanding here.. Right now terminal says when I do this again " relation "test_table" already exists"

Comment: I don't have an .env file. Could that be it?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether postgres expect case sensitive query (specifically table name) executed through pg-promise or not.

As per the error, nodejs is able to make the connection with postgres.

Comment: Can you restate that? I don't understand what you are directing me to cgeck

Comment: I means to say. if your table name created with "Test_table" (T is capital) then must have to fire query with T capital in your table name. So you first check the table definition in postgres and use same table name while making query. Refer https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4491A34B.3040704@tgice.com

Comment: No, I copy pasted from heroku's tutorial and just tried creating a new table the same way.

Answer (score 0):

for create new table you should run this code :

```
heroku pg:psql
```

then for add table to your database run this code on cmd again :

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(id integer, name text);
```

its very similar to mySQL database , you can run other querys like insert too.