# heroku DATABASE_URL is undefined in nodejs app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, pg

Heroku site states that the DATABASE_URL is setup automatically for you.  I used the command 
`heroku config`
to confirm that the DATABASE_URL is indeed set.

However when I use the pg package command

```
const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
});
```

and do a `console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL)`, the variable reads as `undefined`.

The other errors that I am getting are:

*UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The server does not support SSL connections*

The complete code is:

```
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config();

const { Client } = require('pg');
const app = express();

console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);

const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: true,
});

 client.connect();

 client.query('SELECT * FROM customers;', (err, res) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (let row of res.rows) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
    }
    client.end();
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.send('Hello World')
});


app.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port`);
});
```

The code works when I use my local postgresql database, but when I try to connect to Heroku's postgres database, the above errors occur.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Where you're getting this error? In your local setup or heroku console?

Comment: The error is in the local setup.

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing and getting the same error :( Did you figure out what the problem is?

Comment: @legend12 The DATABASE_URL will be defined only in the heroku production environment. You'll obviously get this error if you try locally.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're not crazy... This isn't working for me either, so I dug in, and it just seems... broken.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19341505/4526479

I see `DATABASE_URL` defined in the heroku `config vars` section in the online heroku dashboard. But it's just undefined in the app.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running into issues connecting to the Heroku Postgres database when you run the project locally.

The `DATABASE_URL` environment variable specified in `heroku config` exists only on the Heroku server and you don't have the environment variable set locally.

Create a `.env` file and include your connection string like so

```
DATABASE_URL=...
```

Here you can include the connection string for the database hosted on Heroku, or your local Postgres database server. Just make sure SSL is configured correctly